# ¿Algoritmo para correr de posición un numero en java?

Tags: java, algoritmos

Hola necesito resolver el algoritmo mencionado en el título, lo que debe hacer el algoritmo es que el número ingresado por el usuario (n) que puede ser de cualquier longitud por ejemplo: 12583. Los números de atrás pasen y se ubiquen detrás de los primeros, es decir que del número ingresado antes 1_2_5_8_3 el número 3 se ubicaría detrás de 1, 8 detrás de 2 y el 5 quedaría de ultimo asi: 13285. He pensado hacerlo con un vector pero no sé que función o método usar para que sin importar el número ingresado el programa separe cada uno de los números y luego correrlos de posición. Agradezco de antemano su ayuda!!!

Comment: Porfavor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/250028/edit) y agrega el código de lo que has intentado, de modo que podamos ayudarte con un error puntual, sino tu pregunta es muy amplia..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizo un bucle for y luego voy cogiendo el String desde la ultima posición (en forma de carácteres) y añadiéndolo a otro nuevo.

`int numero=1234;
String aux=""+numero; //Así paso un entero a cadena de texto
String sal="";
for(int i=aux.length-1;i!=0;i--){
salida+=""+aux.charAt(i); //Lo veo una forma rápida de pasar de char a String
}
//Y ya si quieres que te devuelva un numero
int salida=Integer.parseInt(sal);`

Comment: se te agradece la ayuda, pero en la plataforma no hacemos tareas; por lo tanto es deber del OP agregar lo que lleva intentado y mostrar de manera clara donde necesita ayuda, saludos y nuevamente gracias por el interés de ayudar